# My app keeps stopping

Tags: android, database, sqlite, emulation

What is wrong with this app? It keeps stopping and LogCat seems referring to module memtrack and an error on database request. I am also using the right emulator with the API requested from the app. I'm new to android coding.

This is my *manifest*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.davide.poste">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

And this is *MainActivity*

```
package com.example.davide.poste;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;

import com.example.davide.poste.Adapter.SearchAdapter;
import com.example.davide.poste.Database.Database;
import com.mancj.materialsearchbar.MaterialSearchBar;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

RecyclerView recyclerView;
RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
SearchAdapter adapter;

MaterialSearchBar materialSearchBar;
List<String> suggestList = new ArrayList<>();

Database database;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Init view
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_search);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    materialSearchBar = (MaterialSearchBar) findViewById(R.id.search_bar);

    //Init DB
    database = new Database(this);

    //Setup search bar
    materialSearchBar.setHint("Search");
    materialSearchBar.setCardViewElevation(10);
    loadSuggestList();
    materialSearchBar.addTextChangeListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            List<String> suggest = new ArrayList<>();
            for(String search:suggestList)
            {
                if(search.toLowerCase().contains(materialSearchBar.getText().toLowerCase()))
                    suggest.add(search);
            }
            materialSearchBar.setLastSuggestions(suggest);

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        }
    });
    materialSearchBar.setOnSearchActionListener(new MaterialSearchBar.OnSearchActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSearchStateChanged(boolean enabled) {
            if(!enabled)
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onSearchConfirmed(CharSequence text) {
            startSearch(text.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onButtonClicked(int buttonCode) {

        }
    });

    //Init Adapter default set all result
    adapter = new SearchAdapter(this,database.getFriends());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

private void startSearch(String text) {

    adapter = new SearchAdapter(this,database.getFriendByName(text));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

private void loadSuggestList() {
    suggestList = database.getNames();
    materialSearchBar.setLastSuggestions(suggestList);
}
}
```

This is the **LogCat**

> 04-08 15:43:15.668 1972-2410/com.android.systemui E/ResourcesManager: failed to add asset path /data/app/com.example.davide.poste-Md6Miz27wpQdWXVZAgMl8w==/base.apk
>      04-08 15:43:15.669 1972-2410/com.android.systemui E/ResourcesManager: failed to add asset path /data/app/com.example.davide.poste-Md6Miz27wpQdWXVZAgMl8w==/base.apk
>      04-08 15:43:15.670 1972-2410/com.android.systemui E/ResourcesManager: failed to add asset path /data/app/com.example.davide.poste-Md6Miz27wpQdWXVZAgMl8w==/base.apk
>      04-08 15:43:15.683 1972-2410/com.android.systemui E/ResourcesManager: failed to add asset path /data/app/com.example.davide.poste-Md6Miz27wpQdWXVZAgMl8w==/base.apk
>      04-08 15:43:15.763 1762-3443/system_process E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
>      04-08 15:43:15.957 1762-3443/system_process E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
>      04-08 15:43:16.241 1762-3429/system_process E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
>      04-08 15:43:15.553 8772-8772/com.example.davide.poste E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.davide.poste, PID: 8772
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.davide.poste/com.example.davide.poste.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
>        Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
>           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
>           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:209)
>           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:193)
>           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:463)
>           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:185)
>           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:177)
>           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:808)
>           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:793)
>           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:696)
>           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:671)
>           at com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteAssetHelper.java:264)
>           at com.example.davide.poste.Database.Database.getNames(Database.java:59)
>           at com.example.davide.poste.MainActivity.loadSuggestList(MainActivity.java:106)
>           at com.example.davide.poste.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:51)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6975)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767) <

**EDIT**: This is the database code

```
package com.example.davide.poste.Database;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder;

import com.example.davide.poste.Model.Friend;
import com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Leandro on 06/04/18.
 */

public class Database extends SQLiteAssetHelper{

private static final String DB_NAME="friend.db";
private static final int DB_VER=1;

public Database(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VER);
}

//Function get all friends
public List<Friend> getFriends()
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();

    String[] sqlSelect={"Id","Name","Address","Email","Phone"};
    String tableName="Friends";

    qb.setTables(tableName);

    Cursor cursor = qb.query(db,sqlSelect,null,null,null,null,null);
    List<Friend> result = new ArrayList<>();
    if(cursor.moveToFirst())
    {
        do {
            Friend friend = new Friend();
            friend.setId(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("Id")));
            friend.setName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Name")));
            friend.setAddress(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Address")));
            friend.setEmail(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Email")));
            friend.setPhone(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Phone")));

            result.add(friend);
        }while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return result;
}

// Function get all friend's name
public List<String> getNames()
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();

    String[] sqlSelect={"Name"};
    String tableName="Friends";

    qb.setTables(tableName);
    Cursor cursor = qb.query(db,sqlSelect,null,null,null,null,null);
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    if(cursor.moveToFirst())
    {
        do {
            result.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Name")));
        }while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return result;
}

//Function get friend by name
public List<Friend> getFriendByName(String name)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();

    String[] sqlSelect={"Id","Name","Address","Email","Phone"};
    String tableName="Friends";

    qb.setTables(tableName);
    Cursor cursor = qb.query(db,sqlSelect,"Name LIKE ?",new String[]{"%"+name+"%"},null,null,null);
    List<Friend> result = new ArrayList<>();
    if(cursor.moveToFirst())
    {
        do {
            Friend friend = new Friend();
            friend.setId(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("Id")));
            friend.setName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Name")));
            friend.setAddress(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Address")));
            friend.setEmail(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Email")));
            friend.setPhone(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Phone")));

            result.add(friend);
        }while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return result;
}
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method).   Something wrong with your database code.

Comment: Post your db code

Comment: I added the database code! @Psypher

Comment: are you running it on android 5.0+?

Comment: I'm running it on Oreo (SDK 26) @Sam

Comment: have you tried getting permission from user? Cause as the documentation says, even after granting permission in manifest file, you need to take permission from user?

Comment: With android marshmallow and above, you have to implement a permission request first, because reading and writing the external storage is a dangerous permission. More information: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: I don't know how to do. I understood how to do request on Manifest, but I don't know it at run time